# "Undefined reference" error while using inheritance and pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

It gives error when I make object of rectangle type and says undefined reference. Kindly resolve. 
I might be doing some mistake as my concept in virtual functions is quite vague

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


class shape{
protected:
string type;
float width;
float height;
public:
shape(){
    type = "shape";
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}

string getType(){
    return type;
}

float getWidth(){
    return width;
}

float getHeight(){
    return height;
}

void setType(string t){
    type = t;
}

void setWidth(float w){
    width = w;
}

void setHeight(float h){
    height = h;
}

virtual float area() = 0;
virtual void display(){
    cout<<"Type : "<<type;
    cout<<"Width :"<<width;
    cout<<"Height :"<<height;
}
};


class rectangle:public shape{
public:
rectangle();
void display();
float area(){
    int A;
    A = width*height;
return A;
}
};



int main(){

rectangle rec;
rec.setHeight(4);
rec.setWidth(5);
rec.display();

}
```

***Error it gives:***

```
04:36:04 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Q1 ****
```

make all 
'Building file: ../src/Q1.cpp'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Q1.d" -MT"src/Q1.o" -o "src/Q1.o"
   "../src/Q1.cpp"
   'Finished building: ../src/Q1.cpp'
' '
'Building target: Q1'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
 g++  -o "Q1"  ./src/Q1.o
    ./src/Q1.o: In function `main':
F:\Semester 2\OOP\Theory\Assignment5- Composition and Inheritance\19I-2167

D\Q1\Debug/../src/Q1.cpp:120: undefined reference to`rectangle::rectangle()'
F:\Semester 2\OOP\Theory\Assignment5- Composition and Inheritance\19I-2167
    D\Q1\Debug/../src/Q1.cpp:123:
undefined reference to `rectangle::display()'
./src/Q1.o:Q1.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV9rectangle[.refptr._ZTV9rectangle]+0x0): undefined reference to`
vtable for rectangle'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:47: Q1] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

```
04:36:06 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2s.243ms)
```

Comment: Your `rectangle` class has no implementations for the constructor `rectangle()` nor the `display()` method

Comment: Hard to understand what you think the error is. The linker tells you that you haven't defined `rectangle` constructor and `rectangle::display`, and you haven't. This doesn't have anything to do with virtual functions, if you declare a function (or constructor) and you use it, then you must define it.

Comment: Since you don't appear to need them, the simple solution would be to delete the declarations for rectangle::rectangle() and rectangle::display().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both inheritance and the presence of pure virtual functions are not the problem. You'd get similar error for

```
class rectangle {
public:
    rectangle();
    void display();
    float area(){
        int A = 42;
        return A;
    }
};


int main(){

    rectangle rec;
    rec.display();

}
```

You declare a constructor and you declare a method `display` and the compiler takes that as a promise that you will provide a definition of them somewhere. The linker cannot find them, hence the error. You have to define those methods.

However, in your code actually both methods are not needed. You can use the compiler generated constructor and you can reuse `shape::display`, hence you can change `rectangle` to:

```
class rectangle : public shape{
public:
    float area(){
        int A;
        A = width*height;
        return A;
    }
};
```